# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k }\binom{n}{k}= H_n$ without the Beta function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I know how to prove

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k }\binom{n}{k}= H_n$$
by tackling it with the beta function.

I was actually wondering if there is a proof of this fact *without using the property of the Beta function* $$B(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

Comment: when $n=1$, your formula says $-1=1$.

Comment: For even $n$ this sum equals $0$ and for $n=2k-1$ it is $-1/k$.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\frac 1k\binom nk=-H_n$?

Comment: You are right I am so sorry, it is $(-1)^{k-1}$ not $(-1)^k$

Comment: @Interestingproblems, not $\frac{1}{\binom {n}{k}}$, but $\binom {n}{k}$. What is also interesting here, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}\binom {n}{k} H_k=\frac {1}{n}$.

Comment: @user514787: You might find (2) and  (3) of *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815103/harmonic-numbers-series-i/816967#816967)* helpful.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer, very nice answer indeed!

Comment: @user514787: Thanks for the nice comment and the credit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> We have
>   \begin{align}
> f_n&=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}\left(\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right)\frac{1}{k}\\
> &=f_{n-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{k}\\
> &=f_{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\\
> &=f_{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\left((1-1)^n-1\right)\\
> &=f_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=H_n}
> \end{align}

*Note:* This can be found for instance as Example 3, section 1.2 in *Combinatorial Identities* by John Riordan.

---

> Another approach is based upon generating functions and the *Euler transform* of a generating series $A(z)$ which is given as
>   \begin{align*}
> A(z)=\sum_{n=  0}^\infty a_nz^n&\quad\longrightarrow\quad
> \frac{1}{1-z}A\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)=\sum_{n= 0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_k\right)z^n\tag{1}\\
> a_n\quad&\quad\longrightarrow\quad\qquad
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_k&
> \end{align*}

Applying the Euler transform (1) to the left-hand side of the identity
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k }\binom{n}{k}= H_n
\end{align*}
we set $a_k=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$ and obtain as generating function
\begin{align*}
A(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}z^k=\ln(1+z)\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> The Euler transform of (2) is
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{1-z}\ln\left(1+\frac{z}{1-z}\right)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}}\right)z^n
> \end{align*}
>   On the other hand we have
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{1-z}\ln\left(1+\frac{z}{1-z}\right)&=\frac{1}{1-z}\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)\\
> &=-\frac{1}{1-z}\ln(1-z)\\
> &=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k\right)\left( \sum_{l=1}^\infty \frac{1}{l}z^l\right)\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{{k+l=1}\atop{k\geq 0,l\geq 1}}^n \frac{1}{l}\right)z^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}z^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\color{blue}{H_n}z^n\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Note:* A proof of the Euler transformation formula can be found e.g.  in [Harmonic Number Identities Via Euler's transform](http://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL12/Boyadzhiev/boyadzhiev3.pdf) by K.N. Boyadzhiev.

Comment: can you please explain me How I Get $\displaystyle f_{n} = f_{n_1}+\frac{1}{n} = H_{n}$, because when i open i am getting $\displaystyle f_{n} = f_{n-(n-1)}+\frac{1}{n-(n-2)}+\frac{1}{n-(n-3)}+\cdots \cdots +\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}..$ Now i am getting $f_{1} = n.$ Then how can we say $f_{n}=H_{n}.$ please explain me. Thanks

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari: I've added a step which might be helpful.

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari: We have $f_n=f_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}=\left(f_{n-2}+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)+\frac{1}{n}=\left(f_{n-3}+\frac{1}{n-2}\right)+\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}=\cdots=H_n$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{\pars{-1}^{k - 1} \over k}{n \choose k} = H_{n}:\ {\LARGE ?}.\quad H_{z}:\ Harmonic\ Number}$.

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{\pars{-1}^{k - 1} \over k}{n \choose k}} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k - 1} \over k}{n \choose n - k} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k - 1} \over k}\bracks{z^{n - k}}
\pars{1 + z}^{n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{n - 1}}
\pars{1 + z}^{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-z}^{k - 1} \over k}
=
\bracks{z^{n - 1}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
\pars{-z}^{k - 1}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k - 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{n - 1}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \pars{-zt}^{k - 1}\,\dd t =
\bracks{z^{n - 1}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}
{1 \over 1 - \pars{-zt}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{n - 1}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\,{\ln\pars{1 + z} \over z} =
\bracks{z^{n}}\,
\lim_{\nu\ \to\ n}\partiald{\pars{1 + z}^{\nu}}{\nu} =
\lim_{\nu\ \to\ n}\partiald{}{\nu}{\nu \choose n}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over n!}\lim_{\nu\ \to\ n}\partiald{}{\nu}
\bracks{\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\nu - n + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over n!}{\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Psi\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{1} -
\Gamma\pars{1}\Psi\pars{1}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{1}}
\\[5mm] = &\ \Psi\pars{n + 1} + \gamma = \bbx{H_{n}}
\end{align}