# Rate of growth of modified alternating harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} {n \choose k}
$$

and wanted to find some function $f(n)$ that grew at the same rate approximately as thw sum. From looking at it graphically, it appears to be $n^{1/p}$ but I am stuck on trying to find $p$ and proving the limit

Comment: What do you mean by $nCr(n,k)$?

Comment: That means $n$ choose $k$. I wasn't sure how to do the parenthesis notation in latex on my phone haha

Comment: I´ve made an edit. Please check if the edit is right.

Comment: Compute the first terms. This should look like the harmonic number $H_n$ (if I am not mistaken).

Comment: @wjmccann There are many answers at this forum, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2983986/prove-sum-k-1n-frac-1k-1k-binomnk-h-n-without-the-beta-fun) Also see the [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D+%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5E%7Bk-1%7D%7D%7Bk%7D*%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D) of wolfram alpha.

Comment: Look up binomial inversion