# Is this sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i{k\choose i}H_{n+k-i}=H_{2n}$ correct?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, harmonic-numbers

Given the double sum, which has a closed form of $H_{2n}$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i{k\choose i}H_{n+k-i}\tag1$$

Where $H_n$ is the [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

$(1)$ is quite an interesting sums which give a neat simple closed form, we encounters it while just messing a round with the [sum calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=dfaf1b7d15e572ae5a1b2fa172ce8657&title=Math%20Help%20Boards:%20Sum%20Calculator&theme=blue). How to go about proving it, we have not ideas.

**How do we go about by showing that $(1)=H_{2n}$?**

note: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}x^k=(1+x)^n\tag2$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}{1\over k}{n\choose k}=H_n\tag3$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has nothing particular to do with harmonic numbers; it works for any sequence $a_n$.

The coefficient of $a_\ell$ in the sum $\sum_k{n\choose k}\sum_i (-1)^i {k\choose i} a_{n+k-i}$
is, with $n+k-i=\ell$,
$$\sum_k {k\choose k-i}{n\choose k}(-1)^i
=\sum_k {k\choose \ell-n}{n\choose k}(-1)^{k-(\ell-n)}={n\choose \ell-n}(1+(-1))^{2n-\ell}.\tag1$$
The second equation uses the identity,
$$\sum_k{k\choose m}{n\choose k}x^{k-m}={n\choose m}(1+x)^{n-m}.\tag2$$

The right hand side of (1) shows that the coefficient of $a_\ell$ is equal to one if $\ell=2n$ and is equal to zero otherwise.
Therefore 
$$\sum_k{n\choose k}\sum_i (-1)^i {k\choose i} a_{n+k-i}=a_{2n}. $$

Answer (score 2):

*Note:* This supplementary information might be useful.

> The main theme in OPs question are so-called *binomial inverse pairs*. A simple example of such pairs is given by sequences $(a_n)_{n\geq 0},(b_n)_{n\geq 0}$ which fulfil for $n\geq 0$ the following identities
>   \begin{align*}
> a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}b_k\qquad\text{resp.}\qquad b_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k+n}\binom{n}{k}a_k\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> One relation implies the other in (1). This can be seen  via *[exponential generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function)*.
>
> Let $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ be two exponential generating functions
>
> $$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!} \qquad\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\qquad  B(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
>
> The  expressions in (1) are the coefficients of
>
> \begin{align*}
> A(x)=B(x)e^x\qquad\text{and}\qquad B(x)=A(x)e^{-x}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   The relationship in (2) is obvious and so the relationship in (1) follows.

The most important characterization of the pair of inverse relation in (1) is the *orthogonal relation* the pair    implies.  This  follows
by  substituting one pair into the other. We obtain for $n\geq 0$

\begin{align*}
a_n&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}b_k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{i+k}\binom{k}{i}a_i\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\sum_{k=i}^n(-1)^{i+k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{i}
\end{align*}
Hence the orthogonal relation is
\begin{align*}
\delta_{ni}=\sum_{k=i}^n(-1)^{i+k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{i}
\end{align*}
with $\delta_{ni}$ the *[Kronecker Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)*.

> Next, we consider the following identity for *Harmonic Numbers*:
>
> \begin{align*}
> H_n&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k}
> \end{align*}
>
> (See e.g. the [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730885) for a proof) and we observe, that $(-1)^{n-1}H_n$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ are a *binomial inverse pair*:
>
> \begin{align*}
> (-1)^{n-1}H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k}&\qquad&\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k-1}H_k
> \end{align*}

**OPs identity**

> We obtain from (1) by substitution of one side into the other
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}b_k&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{k-i}\binom{k}{i}a_{i}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{i}\binom{k}{i}a_{k-i}=a_n
> \end{align*}
>
> Setting $a_n=H_{n+p}$ with $p$ constant, the claim follows when setting $p=n$.
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{i}\binom{k}{i}H_{p+k-i}=H_{n+p}}
> \end{align*}