# Convergence series, can we have positive sequence terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am reading this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107961/if-a-series-converges-then-the-sequence-of-terms-converges-to-0/632994). According to @ItsNotObvious when we have the series

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = L $$ then $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = 0$$

It is possible to impose other additional conditions to the sequence $a_n$ so as the above equations to hold for $a_n \geq 0$?

**EDIT:** Thanks to `@WishofStar` comment I found the following theorem

> A series of nonnegative terms converges if and only if its partial sums form a bounded sequence (Rudin).

So, if we have that $a_n$ is a bonded sequence can we say that it's partial sums are also bounded and thus based on the theorem the terms $a_n$ has to be non-negative?

Comment: If the series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^na_k$ is monotonically increasing, then surely it is.

Comment: @WishofStar Is it possible to elaborate it a little more? I have little knowledge of real-analysis.

Comment: What do you mean "come up with"?  The $a_n$ could be positive, negative, or $0$.

Comment: I mean if there can be other conditions on $a_n$ so as  to have $a_n \geq 0$ (I did a small edit.).

Comment: Do you mean to ask if we can *conclude* that the terms $a_n$ are all non-negative, given conditions on the series? If so, the, @WishofStar has given you the answer.

Comment: Can we use @WishofStar statement when $L=0$?