# Decreasing sequence term sign for zero convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given a convergent series 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = 0 $$ for an decreasing sequence $\{a_n\}$. Can we make any deductions on the sign of sequence terms $a_n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ is decreasing and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = 0$, then $a_n = 0$ $\forall n$.

To see this, we first show that $a_n \geq 0$. Suppose not, so $a_1 = q < 0$. Then since the sequence is decreasing, $a_n \leq q$ $\forall n$. Then:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty q = -\infty
$$
Which is not possible.

We then observe that $a_1 = 0$ necessarily. This is because if $a_1 > 0$, then since $a_n \geq 0$ $\forall n$, we have that:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \geq a_1 > 0
$$
Which is, again, a contradiction.

This means that we have $0 = a_1 \geq a_2 \geq a_3 \geq \cdots \geq 0$. The only possibility is that $a_n = 0$ $\forall n$.

Comment: (+1) You saved me some time. But I suspect that the OP will change the question. I hope that I am wrong.

Comment: Generally, I know that if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = 0 $$ then $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = 0.$$ So if the sequence is decreasing then **all** sequence terms must equal to zero? [Sorry for my naive comment but I am not familiar with sequences and series]

Comment: You don't need $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ to be zero. As long as the sum converges, you can conclude that $a_n \to 0$ (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107961/if-a-series-converges-then-the-sequence-of-terms-converges-to-0/632994)). In this case, if you restrict further that 1) the sum to be zero and 2) $(a_n)$ is decreasing, then all terms will be zero.

Comment: Thanks again things are more clear! Please let me ask something last hoping it is not out of the scope. Alternatively, If  the sequence $a_n$ is *increasing* we also conclude to $a_n=0~\forall n$?

Comment: Yes we can. We can just reverse all the inequalities in my solution.