# Negative convergent series intuition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am interested on the behavior of the series $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k < 0 $$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a^* $. Can we say that this series converges? Also, is it possible to define any condition on $a_k$ (e.g., decreasing sequence) in order to conclude that $a_k <0$? Sorry for my naive question I am not experienced with series.

Comment: The question is clear but I’m afraid that it will be deemed naive and be voted to close...

Comment: If the limit exists, the series is said to verge, whatever the sign of the limit. As to the sign of its terms, I know of no obvious answer.

Comment: If the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ exists ( positive or negative) then it is easy to see that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_k=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k < 0$ (or, as it is usually written, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k < 0$, you're assuming that the limit exists. In other words, the sum indeed converges. One can show that if the sum converges, [then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ necessarily](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107961/if-a-series-converges-then-the-sequence-of-terms-converges-to-0/632994).

However, the converse is not true, i.e. to $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$, then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ may or may not converge. The most classic and famous example is the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), where $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Clearly $a_n = \frac{1}{n} \to 0$, but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for you interest. Can we make any deduction on the sign of $a_k$ if we know that $a_k$ is an increasing or decreasing sequence? In other words, can we know if $a_k$ approaches zeros from the negative or positive?

Comment: If $a_k$ is increasing or decreasing (not necessarily strict), then we must have $a_k \leq 0$ and $a_k \geq 0$ necessarily. As a result, if $a_k$ is increasing then $a_k \to 0$ from the negative sign (and the opposite if $a_k$ is decreasing).